# Getting key error while setting and getting cookie

Tags: python, django, session, session-cookies, keyerror

I'm getting a weird exception while setting and getting the cookie in Django.
I'm getting key error while trying to print the cookie value. Could someone please tell me the reason by looking at the stack trace http://dpaste.com/3M3ZKXW

```
def sessionHandler(request):
    userName = request.GET.get('uname')
    response = HttpResponse("Setting the cookie now")
    response.set_cookie('cookie_user_name', userName)
    return JsonResponse({'Response': 'success'})


def login(request):
    cookie_user = request.COOKIES['cookie_user_name']
    print("################################")
    print(cookie_user)
    UserName = {"Name": global_user_name}
    return render(request, 'login/login.html', UserName)
```

Exception Type: KeyError at /NewHandBook/welcome
Exception Value: 'cookie_user_name'

Comment: Did you visit sessionHandler first before going to login?

Comment: The code will break if a cookie has not been set.

Comment: @DanielRoseman yes!!! I have executed sessionHandler method before executing login and also printing cookie value inside sessionHandler also throwing the same exception.

Comment: @ababak could you please tell me is there any way that i can check if the cookie is set apart from checking in browser console.

Comment: @vivek.p.nmanu just use `cookie_user = request.COOKIES.get('cookie_user_name')` and verify that `cookie_user is not None`

Answer (score 0):

### Why it's not working

You are setting the cookie on the response, so only the next request from the client after running through the middleware will have the cookie. With or without the middleware, this first request to the server from any client will *never* have this cookie set (or any other cookie).

Sidenote:
It's better to use failsafe code here: The login page should not break just because a GET parameter was not set, anyway. It shouldn't even return an error if this is the entry point to your site. I'm guessing you just want to display a nice "welcome back" message.

The way of your cookie is like this:

```
CLIENT: /login?uname=foobar
 -> request w/o cookie
 -> middleware sets *response* cookies
 -> /login handler checks *request* cookies: None
```

The way of cookies in general is:

```
CLIENT: first request
 -> server sets response cookies
 -> server sends response (preferrably 2**)
CLIENT: displays response and stores cookies
CLIENT: next request with cookies
 -> server reads cookies from request (e.g. session+CSRF cookies)
 -> server sends response (again with cookies, CSRF-Token etc.)
```

### How to make it work

Cookies are something that the server uses to check back with the client.

In your case you are already sending the info you want from the client via GET parameter. You don't need a cookie in this case, because this is not something you want the client to store but instead you want to process it on the server (and it has already reached the server).

Simplest solution to illustrate:

```
def login(request):
    userName = request.GET.get('uname')
    print("################################")
    print(userName)
    UserName = {"Name": userName}
    return render(request, 'login/login.html', UserName)
```

So, you just need to find a way to store it in the middleware and read it back in the login handler. This is what the session is for. You have a session as soon as the first request comes in from the client (with Django).
The session lives through the login, and you will be able to access any data stored within it as long as the session lives (that is: as long as the session cookie is stored on the client and has not expired).

Make sure to add your middleware to the chain after Django's session middleware.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/sessions/